# Copy List elements N times using Stream API

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Is there a way to copy some List (or combined string if necessary) N times in Java using Stream API

If the list consists of `{"Hello", "world"}` and N = 3, the result should be `{"Hello", "world", "Hello", "world", "Hello", "world"}`

What I've done so far is to get combined String element and I am not sure how to procees to copy it N times. While I can do it externally, I would like to see if it is possible to do with the help of streams

```
Optional<String> sentence = text.stream().reduce((value, combinedValue) -> { return value + ", " + combinedValue ;});
```

I would like to use stream, because I am planning to continue with other stream operations after the one above

Comment: The code you have given is probably better replaced with `String.join(", ", text)`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you are right, just that I would like to use stream, because I am planning to continue with other stream operations after the one asked in the question

Comment: You should specify that in your question. The answers people give you assume that you want some kind of an end product, either a list or a string.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I believe I specified it in the question, will try to edit it to be more clear though, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Collections.nCopies`:

```
List<String> output =
    Collections.nCopies(3,text) // List<List<String>> with 3 copies of 
                                // original List
               .stream() // Stream<List<String>>
               .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<String>
               .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<String>
```

This will product the `List`:

```
[Hello, World, Hello, World, Hello, World]
```

for your sample input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `IntStream` and `flatMap` to connect the `text` List multiple times:

```
List<String> result = IntStream.range(0, 3)
        .mapToObj(i -> text)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result looks like this:

```
[Hello, World, Hello, World, Hello, World]
```

Comment: Avoid boxing by replacing `.boxed() .flatMap(i -> text.stream())` with `.mapToObj(i -> text) .flatMap(List::stream)`

Comment: Why should I avoid using `.boxed()`? Can you explain it that a bit more?

Comment: It doesn’t apply in this simple scenario with that small range, but for large ranges, `.boxed()` implies potentially creating a new `Integer` instance for every element (outside the byte range), whereas `.mapToObj(i -> text)` always maps to the same, already existing object. It’s not that you should avoid boxing at all costs, but here, the alternative has the same simplicity, so why not use it (and then, it will be on par with what happens behind the scenes in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55493757/2711488))

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Holger. I updated my answer.